# d3js - in scaleband missing ticks

Tags: d3.js

Here is my d3js v4 code. It's just part for my stacked bar chart.
Scaling looks good, the only problem are missing tick values. Where is the problem? Y axis works fine.

```
  var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, width])
    .round(true)
    .paddingInner(0.1);

  x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
            return d.name;
        }));

  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(x).tickFormat(function(d) {
            return d;
    } );

  svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (height) + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.6em")
        .attr("dy", ".10em")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "rotate(-65)" 
            });
```

Comment: Please add a [mre] of your code, preferably using a runnable Stack snippet - or a jsFiddle/Codepen if that doesn't work

Comment: Did you [`nice()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#continuous_nice) the domain?